# using a devexpress custom confirm popup on pageunload

Tags: javascript, devexpress, devextreme

So I've been trying to prompt a confirmation before a page unloads  but I don't want this default ok cancel browser confirmation popup so following the examples on how to do this I've been trying to replace it with a Devexpress popup or confirmation dialogs without success,
I am fairly new to javascript and don't really get what's causing the issue.

```
          function confirmExit(data){
           setTimeout(function (){
           var result =  DevExpress.ui.dialog.confirm("Are you sue","Confirm");
           result.done(function (retVal){
         
                
            if (retVal == true) {
              
                return true;
            }
            else {
                window.stop();
                return false;
            }
       
           });

           });

      }
       $(window).bind('beforeunload',  confirmExit);
```

the difference between normal confirm and devexpress popup or confirm dialog is that the later returns a promise .. but for some reason the code above doesn't even stop the page from unloading.

any direction and help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad news, what you are looking for cannot be done with the beforeunload event. I show you below a code that would work. The following code would show the browser's default alert with the message "If you exit the existing changes will be lost" or something like that. This is because the event is fired only when you interacted with the page and then want to exit.

```js
      window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (e) => {
        //console.log(e)
        let dialogText = "something";
        e.returnValue = dialogText;
        return dialogText;
      });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" />
    <a href="./test.html">exit</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Each browser works a little differently with this event, but in short. If you don't return at the end it won't work. Simply displaying a custom message is not possible. You can find more information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event

### update

If in your case you want to display a warning message when a user clicks on a link, you can do the following. Create a button and style it as a link. Bind the button to a click event that will open the custom modal. And in the confirm button of the modal assign a click event that redirects to the destination page. Here is an example with bootstrap:

```js
      function exit(){
        window.location.replace("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71811083/using-a-devexpress-custom-confirm-popup-on-pageunload/71878906?noredirect=1#comment127031969_71878906")
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <a
      type="button"
      class="fs-2"
      title="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71811083/using-a-devexpress-custom-confirm-popup-on-pageunload/71878906?noredirect=1#comment127031969_71878906"
      data-bs-toggle="modal"
      data-bs-target="#exampleModal"
    >
      Go to a third party page
    </a>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div
      class="modal fade"
      id="exampleModal"
      tabindex="-1"
      aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
      aria-hidden="true"
    >
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Personalized Message</h5>
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn-close"
              data-bs-dismiss="modal"
              aria-label="Close"
            ></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">Are you sure","Confirm</div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-secondary"
              data-bs-dismiss="modal"
            >
              Close
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="exit()">Confirm and Exit</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    

    <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
    <!--
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

This is a basic idea. You can create code to do this with all the links on your website or just one.

Comment: thanks for the response I started thinking this was the case since this question was up for so long and got no answers , I am aware of how the default behavior works ,  so my question now would be if this won't work in the beforeunload_event  is there any other way I can look at to achieve my goal ?

Comment: @FadiBanna check the update

Comment: yeah this is the approach that first got to my mind the issue is that as you pointed out it solves the part when a user clicks on a link and not when they press back button for example but as it appears this is the only way.

Comment: Right @FadiBanna

Comment: @FadiBanna If the clarification was useful to you, you can accept the answer.